# Convert date to milliseconds in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

```
      DateTimePicker datePicker2 = DateTimePicker.createInstance();
      datePicker2.doModal();
      Calendar cal = datePicker2.getDateTime();
      Date date = cal.getTime();
      TimeZone _timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

      int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int date =cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
      int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
      int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
      int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

      int miliS33 = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

I get all fields of selected date using 'datetimepicker` but i just want to convert this date in to milliseconds ,How could i do this..i have already used

`long gmtOffset = _timeZone.getOffset(1, year, month, date,day,miliS);` but this does not work for me .

pls Give suggestion with some code...!

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
date.getTime();
```

Remember this method

> *"Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*"

Comment: @mulya, `getTimeInMillis()` is a protected method, not public.

Comment: I got solution using this..   <calendar>.getTime().getTime()

Comment: @sachin, that's exactly what Mister Smith told you to use.  `date = cal.getTime()`.  You should accept his answer.